# Display a different value in Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm utilizing the Select component from Material UI, Here's what I'm attempting:https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-water-zh16n?file=/src/App.js

Given:

- an object of account, say, {id:1, name:'name'}, I'd like to select a 'name' and setState with its value, the code sandbox is at this stage.

Issue:

- The MUI select renders no visual value after doing this, my goal is to have the Select component render out the name of the value that has been selected

Ideal:

- The name is present in the dropdown, and when selected, the name populates the Select
- the onChange takes in the value prop and utilizes it

Greatly appreciate any thoughts, I've attempted to use the renderValue prop to no avail, thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select dropdown should always reflect the `value: state.selected`.
To render the `name` present in the dropdown.

We will use the `state.selected` which is `id` and find that `id` among the `state.accounts` to show the relevant `name`.

Modified your code. Please find below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-gareth-e6gqs

Comment: Amazing! I really appreciate the post! 

This was exactly what I was looking for, I had not seen much documentation on how to use renderValue so that also confused me.

Once more, thank you!